# Handling aspect ratio of lazy loading images with different dimensions to avoid content jump

Tags: html, css, image, lazy-loading

With the help of 
`padding-top: calc(height / widht * 100%);`
I can handle lazy loading images to avoid content jump.

But this solution works perfectly only when all the images are in same dimension.

How can we handle content jump when rendering different dimension images?

FYI: For lazy loading images i'm using [lazysizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes)

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: calc(100 / 411 * 100%);
}

.wrapper_img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <p>Test 001</p>

    <div>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <img class="wrapper_img" src="https://placehold.it/411x100" />
      </div>
    </div>

    Test 002

    <div>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <img class="wrapper_img" src="https://placehold.it/150x100" />
      </div>
    </div>

    Test 003

    <div>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <img class="wrapper_img" src="https://placehold.it/411x600" />
      </div>
    </div>

    Test 004

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[Here](https://jsbin.com/defetovuza/edit?html,css,output) is the link to JSBin.

Comment: then define a differente class for each image

Comment: can you please clarify what do you mean by `content jump`?

Comment: @Hitmands i meant content reflow https://css-tricks.com/content-jumping-avoid/ https://www.voorhoede.nl/en/blog/say-no-to-image-reflow/

Comment: Standard defines you need to have width/height property on the image

Answer (score 0):

@sravis are you dealing with a limited set of aspect ratios? If so, then you can just use different classes for each aspect ratio. If not, then setting the `img`'s, `height` and `width` upfront can prevent content reflow.

Comment: Images are uploaded by users. This images are dimension free. Meaning user can upload image of any dimension eg: 400x100  and/or 1080x720. Before rendering this images i'm sending request to image optimization service to get the appropriate image dimension based on the user device screen width.

Comment: This means setting the H/W in the image tag NOT CSS. So `<img height="300" width="400" />` If you wait for the CSS you'll likely cause a repaint. You could also look into using a [native lazy load](https://web.dev/native-lazy-loading) solution.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't have a set of aspect ratios, you will need the image sizes (or aspect ratios) if you render the html. 
Specifying the image width/height attributes is nice but won't solve your problem.

What you can do

- One Idea would be to provide the aspect ratios to your wrapper div as *inline style* using your implementation using the padding-top.
- Another idea using inline-styles with custom css variables as those are [broadly supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables). Take a look at the snippet. This is an example that has a fixed wrapper width with a border and upscales the images.

Whatever you decide to use

- take care of broken images, which might break your aspect ratio.
- Images that are too small to fill your whole wrapper will look a little bit lost in your layout. Either use [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) and [object-postion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position) to fix this - or just ommit the max-widh like in the snippet to scale them up.

```css
/* css for wrapper only for demonstration purposes and not really needed */

.wrapper {
  width: 300px; /* just to limit the size */
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* tricky stuff starts here */

[style*="--aspect-ratio"] {
  position: relative;
}

[style*="--aspect-ratio"]::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: calc(100% / (var(--aspect-ratio)));
}

[style*="--aspect-ratio"] > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <p>Test 001</p>

    <div>
      <div class="wrapper" style="--aspect-ratio:411/100">
        <img class="wrapper_img" src="https://placehold.it/411x100" />
      </div>
    </div>

    Test 002 (broken by intention)

    <div>
      <div class="wrapper" style="--aspect-ratio:150/100">
        <img class="wrapper_img" src="https://broken-placehold.it/150x100" />
      </div>
    </div>

    Test 003

    <div>
      <div class="wrapper" style="--aspect-ratio:411/600">
        <img class="wrapper_img" src="https://placehold.it/411x600" />
      </div>
    </div>


Test 004

    <div>
      <div class="wrapper" style="--aspect-ratio:150/100">
        <img class="wrapper_img" src="https://placehold.it/150x100" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it getting the image size from the file (php):

```
$data = getimagesize("path/to/file");
```

calculating the aspect ratio:

```
$aspectratio = $data[0]/$data[1];
```

an set it as css style to the parent div:

```
<div class="portfolio-wrap" style="aspect-ratio: '.round($aspectratio,1).';">
   <img/>
</div>
```